# SecurityException using scoped storage in some devices

Tags: android, scoped-storage

Im looking in google play crashes in some devices, like Samsung and Nokia, api 29 and 30.

Logs:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:2385)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2369)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2352)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2294)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider (IActivityManager.java:6680)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider (ActivityThread.java:7643)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContextImpl.java:3090)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContentResolver.java:2484)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:1170)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:1118)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:1074)
  at FileUtils.getFileName (FileUtils.java:69)
  at MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:88)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8198)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8182)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3765)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl (ActivityManagerService.java:8965)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl (ActivityManagerService.java:8804)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider (ActivityManagerService.java:9505)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact (IActivityManager.java:2840)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact (ActivityManagerService.java:3617)
```

Permissions only for android < 28:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

The crash code:

```
 public static String getFileName(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getPath();
            int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (cut != -1) {
                result = result.substring(cut + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Manifest:

```
        <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

  <activity
                android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

provider_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
</paths>
```

This is working well in the 90% of the devices.
Any idea why is crashing? I think that can be for open some file without permissions, but I'm unable to reproduce it

Comment: `Any idea why is crashing in the rest of devices?` Yes. That is because you do not catch those exceptions.

Comment: For the rest you did not tell what your problem has to do with scoped storage nor did you tell what your code should do.

Comment: The error is for dont ask for permissions, with the new scoped storage in apis > 28 this can be done without permission, Im just reading the filename picked by the user using the native picker

Comment: No. Not when picking the file. As we can see `at FileUtils.getFileName (FileUtils.java:69)
  at MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:88)` in the logcat. So you do it at a different moment. Directly in onCreate(). So the next day or so. All unclear.

Comment: The problem is here:   at FileUtils.getFileName (FileUtils.java:69), calling the query with the resolver

Comment: You do not show where you are getting the `Uri` from. There is no requirement for every `Uri` to support a `query()`, let alone one that returns any of the `OpenableColumns`.

Comment: The problem is not well-defined. the only thing that's clear is `SecurityException` that can be thrown in many circumstances.

Comment: My app is a document reader, when the user opens some files, (action share or action view) my app raises SecurityException working with the uri, what do you need to understand the circumstances?

Comment: can you tell me flowing thing    1. in which api verson (27,28,29,30) app is crushing 2.are you taking permission in runtime permission in your app

Comment: @AakashKumar 28,29,30,31,32, Im not asking for permissions in runtime, I think it is not necessary with scoped storage

Answer (score 0):

The app that owns the file that triggers the intent to open a document may have not granted READ permissions. For example

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // user's app may not have specified this
```

Your app needs to do the following for Android 10 and above:

1. Following the best practices outlined in [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), request the [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.
2. If the URI points to files in restricted locations like `Android/data` and `Android/obb`, your app would not be able to READ it even if it has the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. In this case, your app should catch the `Exception` and show an appropriate error message to the user.

So in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` do something like the following

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // on Android 10+ request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
        if (hasPermissions(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            try {
                String name = FileUtils.getFileName(this, URI);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showToast("Error loading file");
            }
        } else {
            requestPermission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

    }
```